# Why does my packery.js + draggabilly.js '.handle' not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am usind this jquery script to initialize packery, add draggabilly to .grid-item elements and toggle the drag functionality on/off.

I don't know much about javascript/jquery, but I've tried comparing my code with examples found on codepen.io and this question:
[Is there a way to make only part of a Packery/Draggabilly container draggable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529613/is-there-a-way-to-make-only-part-of-a-packery-draggabilly-container-draggable)

Example and documentation for Packery and Draggabilly: https://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html#draggabilly

https://draggabilly.desandro.com/
Draggabilly example on codepen: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/xbyEyO

None seem to get my code working with a handle.

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="">
      <button class="toggle-drag-button">Toggle drag</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
    <div class="grid-item">
     <div class="title-wrapper">
       <span>FontAwesome</span><span>Title text</span>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
var $grid = $('.grid').packery({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
  percentPosition: true,
  horizontalOrder: true
});

// collection of Draggabillies
var draggies = [];
var isDrag = false;

// make all grid-items draggable
$grid.find('.grid-item').each( function( i, gridItem ) {
  var draggie = new Draggabilly( gridItem, {
    handle: '.title-wrapper'
  });
  draggies.push( draggie );
  // bind drag events to Packery
  $grid.packery( 'bindDraggabillyEvents', draggie );
});

$('.toggle-drag-button').on( 'click', function() {
  var method = isDrag ? 'disable' : 'enable';
  draggies.forEach( function( draggie ) {
    draggie[ method ]();
  });
  // switch flag
  isDrag = !isDrag;
});
</script>
</body>
```

The packery and draggabilly works as expected, even with a CSS3 Grid inside hosting links and images, but when adding {handle: '.title-wrapper'} nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works without the handle but doesn't after then you've either misspelled the value (so handle isn't able to match your selector) or your markup isn't the way you've laid out. If it doesn't work when you remove the second argument to the Draggabilly constructor then your initialization logic is wrong. PS I assume you didn't include the button with class .`toggle-drag-button` when you simplified your attached code but it is missing from the markup and your click handler doesn't bind to anything.

-- Edit --

In your markup you have both .grid-sizer and .gutter-sizer. I assume you don't need both.

Your problem is your gutter combined with percentPosition. See working example here: https://codepen.io/yonywithawhy/pen/qgdjar

Make sure you have a width set on `.gutter-sizer`. If you don't you will see the second block jump super far down. It will appear that the blocks aren't draggable but that's not true - it's just difficult to see. If you drag the bottom div all the way to the top and release you'll see the boxes change order. The percentPosition can't be used without a width size.

Comment: I've included my button - thank you for noticing :) I've checked my values and they are spelled correctly. I agree about the initialization, just can't figure out where the issue lies.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The issue has been solved :)